# Silverlight MediaElement issue

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, visual-studio-2008, video-processing

I am using Silverlight 3.0 + .Net 3.5 + VSTS 2008 + C# to develop a simple video application using MediaElement of Silverlight.

I have two videos and I want to play them at the same time (similar to picture in picture effect) -- i.e. a part of the two videos are overlapped when they are playing (the same concept of Z-Order in UI design). I want to play one MediaElement on top of the other MediaElement, and I am wondering how to assign the overlap order (similar to set Z-Order UI element, but I did not find MediaElement has Z-Order property)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could place your `MediaElement` inside of a `Canvas`. The Elements inside a `Canvas` Element inherit it's `Canvas.ZIndex` Attribute.

```
<Canvas x:Name="MediaPlayerPanel" Width="200" Height="200">  
  <MediaElement x:Name="Media1" Height="200" Width="200" Source="file1.wmv" Canvas.ZIndex="1" />
  <MediaElement x:Name="Media2" Canvas.Top="20" Canvas.Left="20" Height="100" Width="100" Source="file2.wmv" Canvas.ZIndex="2" />
</Canvas>
```

This should work for you!

Comment: How to set ZIndex dynamically in code? And how to set Canvas.Top dynamically in code?

Comment: In Silverlight, it's always the best idea to not set anything in Code but use DataBinding. For example, set the Value of Canvas.Top to `{Binding TopProperty}` and define a public Property called TopProperty returning "int". Do you need more instructions? Some general hints on how to use DataBinding: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278072%28VS.95%29.aspx